# Which firewall Ports to open for SSH in my setup that uses a bridge firewall?

Tags: ssh, firewall

I can't connect to a LAN PC by SSH if I don't open **all ports** to the LAN PC in the LAN bridge firewall.

- I opened 22 and ICMP, with no result.
- Then I opened also 53,80,443: no result. (TCP and UDP)
- I tried also 53 to 445: no results.
- I tried **netstat** on target pc, and the ports open are: 139, 22, 5432, 25, 9050, 139, 80, 323, 523.

What do you suggest?

Further explanation:

- Both PCs are in the same LAN, 192.168.1.x.
- Target PC (SSH server) is behind a firewall (bridge firewall).
- If I set open all ports to target ssh server firewall, I can connect to SSH using port 22.
- If I open just ports 22 and ICMP, I can't connect to SH server.
- Firewall is not the LAN gateway/DHCP server/router/etc.
- A bridge firewall is a device with 2 ethernet ports, transparent to LAN, that is a firewall between ports.
- I just discovered the SSH server OS is a virtual guest on a ESXI server.

Comment: What is the target computer, which SSH server version it has, and was anything non-standard done during its installation? What is "brige firewall"?

Comment: "Bridge" firewall, OpenSSH 7.4p1

Comment: It would be better to add the configuration file of the firewall to your post.

Comment: Note logically "I can't if I don't open" is *not* equivalent to "I can if I open". It may as well be "I can't if I don't open *and* I can't if I open". So… Can or cannot you ssh if you open all ports? Now I assume you can. How exactly this "opening all ports" look like? When it works, does the client use the standard TCP port 22? or is there some custom config on the client side?

Comment: where is the client system in relation to the server? are they both on the LAN, or is one of them outside your network? we're not really clear on what it is you are calling "LAN Bridge Firewall".

Comment: If it's a regular SSH host, it should be on port 22 and you should not need to open any other ports. How is the Bridge Firewall configured and is it truly transparent? Does the SSH host itself have a firewall running?

Comment: do you have return traffic allowed? ssh is asymetric in how it uses ports, so the client will connect from an unpredictable TCP port above 1024 to TCP\22, so return traffic to the client will be from TCP\22 to the client port whatever that is. make sure that you have rules running both ways, allow traffic arriving on NicX to TCP\22 from any TCP, and arriving on NicY from TCP\22 to any TCP where Nics X and Y are the interfaces of your bridge.

Comment: You could open all ports then try to inspect things with Wireshark(packet sniffer) and try to see what ports are required / what protocols are going on. And try manually shutting down half the ports, see if that changes anything etc. (as troubleshooting steps)

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by https://superuser.com/users/171793/frank-thomas is what solved my problems.

I had to open port 22 to **any port** and **any port** to 22.